# Fetching xmpp resource string using pidgin dbus python api

Tags: python, xmpp, dbus, pidgin

I was using the pidgin dbus api to print the names of my gtalk buddies and their status by writing the following python code snippet:

```
import dbus


# Initiate a connection to the Session Bus
bus = dbus.SessionBus()

# Associate Pidgin's D-Bus interface with Python objects
obj = bus.get_object("im.pidgin.purple.PurpleService", "/im/pidgin/purple/PurpleObject")
purple = dbus.Interface(obj, "im.pidgin.purple.PurpleInterface")


# Iterate through every active account
for acctID in purple.PurpleAccountsGetAllActive():
   for buddy in purple.PurpleFindBuddies(acctID,""):
      print purple.PurpleBuddyGetName(buddy),'Online' if purple.PurpleBuddyIsOnline(buddy) else 'Offline'
```

In Pidgin when i hover my mouse over a particular buddy, it also shows the Resource string of that buddy for example **gtalk, android etc.**.. which tells me which resource the user is logged in from.

Is there a way to fetch this Resource string using pidgins dbus api or some other way ?

Please Help
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

you can use the script from the [wiki page](http://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/DbusHowto):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def my_func(account, sender, message, conversation, flags):
    print sender, "said:", message

import dbus, gobject
from dbus.mainloop.glib import DBusGMainLoop
dbus.mainloop.glib.DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)
bus = dbus.SessionBus()

bus.add_signal_receiver(my_func,
                        dbus_interface="im.pidgin.purple.PurpleInterface",
                        signal_name="ReceivedImMsg")

loop = gobject.MainLoop()
loop.run()
```

`sender` here will be smth like this:
'example@gmail.com/androidXXXXXXXX' in case of using android or 
 'example@gmail.com/gmail.XXXXXXXX' for gtalk or 
'example@gmail.com/XXXXXXXX' for other im, where X is a hex value.